# TouchesBegan recognised in next view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];

    NSLog(@"touch recognised");

    CGPoint location = [aTouch locationInView:_mainView];

    __block NSString *option = [[NSString alloc] init];
    __block NSString *type = [[NSString alloc] init];

    for (Selectors *tempView in _mainView.subviews) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(tempView.frame, location)) {
            NSLog(@"%@ : %@", tempView.option, tempView.type);

            option = tempView.option;
            type = tempView.type;

            break;
        }
    }


    [self moveToNextWeldCustomViewWithOption:option andType:type];


}
```

Is in my previous UIVIewController - then we present the next UIViewController here

```
-(void)moveToNextWeldCustomViewWithOption:(NSString *)option andType:(NSString *)type {

    WeldDesignViewController *lobby = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WeldDesignViewController"];

    lobby.option = option;
    lobby.type = type;

    [self presentViewController:lobby animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

In the next UIViewController I don't do anything until the viewDidAppear method - However, the touches began is still being recognised in the next viewcontroller.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are expecting and what is happening instead. Are you wanting to get these touches in the previous view controller? Are you not wanting them but getting them?

Comment: @ChrisTrahey in brief, the next viewcontroller is logging the touches which are in the previous viewcontroller.

Comment: So, view controller number 2 is no longer on screen, but is getting the touches? Are these two view controllers the same class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that the VC you are calling "lobby" is being deallocated after you present it. This takes it out of consideration in the responder chain. Move that reference to be a property of the presenting view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) WeldDesignViewController* lobby;
// ...
-(void)moveToNextWeldCustomViewWithOption:(NSString *)option andType:(NSString *)type {

   self.lobby = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WeldDesignViewController"];

    lobby.option = option;
    lobby.type = type;

    [self presentViewController:self.lobby animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

You may also need to implement `touchesBagan` in the presented VC, as it is probably following the responder chain to the previous controller.

Comment: Unfortunately after reading I was hoping it would've been this simple and I'd missed a pretty silly mistake. However, I'm still able to touch the views from the previous viewcontroller in the next viewcontroller.

Comment: In essence, I can click in the same locations as the views were previously and they'll still log from the touches began in the previous viewcontroller.

Comment: `2017-02-25 19:28:30.079 Ultra Plotter[1826:270732] touch recognised
2017-02-25 19:28:30.080 Ultra Plotter[1826:270732] Plate : Single Bevel
2017-02-25 19:28:30.081 Ultra Plotter[1826:270732] Warning: Attempt to present <WeldDesignViewController: 0x7fa51d809750> on <TypeOfWeldViewController: 0x7fa51ac051c0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` in ViewController2

Comment: Gosh that last log line tells a lot! It looks like the issue is "upstream", your TypeOfWeldViewController's view is not in the window hierarchy... how is that presented?

Comment: from the previous ViewController 
`-(IBAction)newWeldPressed:(id)sender {
    TypeOfWeldViewController *lobby = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TypeOfWeldViewController"];
    
    [self presentViewController:lobby animated:NO completion:nil];
}`

Comment: But remember, it's only causing the issue because we're not currently in that viewController - it's running the action from the TouchesBegan method in the `TypeOfWeldViewController` in the `WeldDesignViewController`

Comment: If easier, I can share my project with you in a private chat?

Comment: Can you try implementing the suggestion in my answer throughout the app and report back? You must retain a strong reference to presented view controllers that survive the scope from which they are presented. This alone will cause all sorts of issues.

Comment: I've fixed the issue. I've literally just created a new method in the ViewController2 for `touchesBegan` and now It's calling within ViewController2 as opposed to ViewController1. If you want to add it to your answer I'll accept along with your suggestion to point strongly to all ViewControllers in the app. I'll also go through and change them now if it'll present me issues as the app grows. Thanks for your help Chris, I appreciate it.

Comment: Updated answer!